# TypeError when using closures in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am executing closure example, Please check the code below

```js
function Counter()
{ 
    var count=0;
    var counterIncrement=function()
    {
        count++;
        console.log(count);            
    }
    return counterIncrement;  
    
}

var v=Counter();
v.counterIncrement();
```

Error: Please explain

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: v.counterIncrement is not a function",
>   "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
>   "lineno": 26,
>   "colno": 3

Comment: It should be Closures!

Comment: You should use `v()` not `v.counterIncrement()`

Comment: v.counterIncrement() doesn't make sense. Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/111111/6643136

Comment: `Counter` returns a function. It doesn't return an object with a property called `counterIncrement`. You could call `v();`, but `v.counterIncrement` is `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Where did you find that "closure example"?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYrtnS3X_Lw&t=30s  please refer once

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

This is an extended answer requested by OP in comment.

So OP was asking what if you have 2 functions within it. How would you call it? Easy, just return an object and assign the function handlers to a property each.

**Example:**

```js
function Counter()
{
    var count=0;
    var counterIncrement = function()
    {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }

    var increment = function(value) {
        count += value;
        console.log(count);
    }

    // return as an object with reference to the functions
    return {
        counterIncrement : counterIncrement,
        increment : increment
    }
}

var v= Counter();
v.counterIncrement();
v.increment(100);
```

---- Previous Answer ------

When you execute `var v=Counter();`, essentially you are executing the function `Counter()` and assigning its return value to `v`.

In this case, `Counter()` would return a reference to the function `counterIncrement`.

So variable `v` now  holds a callable function named `counterIncrement()`. When you do `v.counterIncrement()`, your javascript engine sees the code as `counterIncrement.counterIncrement()`, which gets resolved into an undefined property. This produces the error message that you were seeing.

Calling just `v()` is sufficient.

```js
function Counter()
{
    var count=0;
    var counterIncrement=function()
    {
        count++;
        console.log(count);
    }
    return counterIncrement;

}

var v= Counter();
v();
```

Comment: but i want to call inside function of Counter() i,e counterIncrement
for suppose i have two functions , when call  v()// it will excute two functions right

Comment: @Bergi you have a point there. Doesn't make sense to init it as 50... not sure what i'm thinking.

Comment: @VeereshKoppula `v` is already the "inside function" so you just invoke it hence `v()`

Comment: Thanks for reply,
my question is: if i have two functions in 1) counterIncrement(), 2Increment()
how to call this two functions  closer please explain am reffer - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYrtnS3X_Lw&t=30s

Comment: Thank you so much , Can please explain  // return as an object with reference to the functions
    return {
        counterIncrement : counterIncrement,
        increment : increment
    }

why you are taking reference with out reference it will not execute , please refer this video,

Comment: @VeereshKoppula I don't understand what you're saying here. The code runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```js
var counter = (function() {
  var count = 0;
  function countval(val) {
    count += val;
  }
  return {
    counterIncrement: function() {
      countval(1);
    },
    counterDecrement: function() {
      countval(-1);
    },
    value: function() {
      return count;
    }
  };   
})();

console.log(counter.value()); 
counter.counterIncrement();
console.log(counter.value()); 
counter.counterDecrement();
console.log(counter.value());
```

If you dont want like this you can call `v();` instead of `v.counterIncrement();`..So code would be

```
var v=Counter();
v();
```

Comment: Try making it less complicated.

Comment: i thought of giving the minimal also but they already posted that answer.

Comment: but i want to call inside function of Counter() i,e counterIncrement
for suppose i have two functions , when call  v()// it will excute two functions right

Comment: if you want to use two function you can add another function in return .. i ll update my answer

Comment: see my second function `counterDecrement` and i called like `counter.counterDecrement();` and getting the vaule from `counter.value()` @Veeresh Koppula

Answer (score 0):

you can slightly modify your code for create an object of `Counter` then you can access the function like `myObject.counterIncrement()`

```
function Counter()
{ 
    var count=0;
    this.counterIncrement = function() //used 'this' for create an object method which can access outside
    {
        count++;
        console.log(count);            
    }
    //return counterIncrement;  //no need to return this method,

}

var v = new Counter();//used 'new' keyword to create an object of 'counter' 
v.counterIncrement();//access ojbect method.

v.counterIncrement();//out put 2
v.counterIncrement();//out put 3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function Counter()
{ 
    var count=0;
    var counterIncrement=function()
    {
        count++;
        console.log(count);            
    }
    return counterIncrement;// Here you are returning function 
}

var v=Counter();
//v.counterIncrement();// This will not call like that 
//Directly call
v();
```

Answer as you like is as following

```
var counter = (function() {
var count = 0;
return {
    counterIncrement: function() {
    count++;
    console.log(count);
    },
  };   
})();
```

Comment: but i want to call inside function of Counter() i,e counterIncrement
for suppose i have two functions , when call  v()// it will excute two functions right

Comment: Okay I am updating my answer as you want

Comment: I have updated as you want please check second example